# Visual Studio 2019 Compare View ScrollBar

Tags: visual-studio, compare, diff, visual-studio-2019

Does anyone know how to get back this scrollbar in the Diff-Tool of Visual Studio 2019?
Why did they remove it?

[image: Compare Window Scrollbar]

Comment: Please vote on the feedback portal: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/406178/its-hard-to-see-changes-in-a-diff.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To re-enable the pre-2019 diff scrollbar, turn on "Show the difference overview margin" under Tools / Options / Text Editor / Advanced.

[image: Options, Text Editor, Advanced, Show the difference overview margin]

Thanks to David Pugh at Microsoft for [providing this answer on the Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/543948/view.html).

Comment: is there also a way to remove the magnifier map on the right side?